# nginx: unknown directive deny in config file with Dokku static deploy

Tags: nginx

I'm getting an "unknown directive" error for `deny` in my nginx confg.

Error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "deny" in /app/nginx/nginx.conf:22
```

Config:

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log stderr;
pid nginx.pid;
daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include mime.types;
  server {
    listen {{ $.PORT }};
    server_name  _;
    {{ if ne $.NGINX_ROOT "" }}
      root /app/www/{{ $.NGINX_ROOT }};
    {{ else }}
      root /app/www;
    {{ end }}
    index index.html;

    # Deny all files by default
    location / { deny all; }

    # Allow access to specific files only
    location = / { }
    location = /favicon.ico { }
    location = /index.html { }
    location = /logo.png { }
  }
}
```

Feel like I'm missing something very obvious here, but I'm just not seeing it.  Any help appreciated.

Edit: `nginx -V`:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 
configure arguments: --with-cpu-opt=generic --prefix=/tmp/build/nginx --with-pcre=../pcre-8.39 --sbin-path=. --pid-path=./nginx.pid --conf-path=./nginx.conf --with-ld-opt=-static --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-file-aio --with-zlib=../zlib-1.2.8 --with-pcre --with-cc-opt='-O2 -static -static-libgcc' --without-http_charset_module --without-http_ssi_module --without-http_userid_module --without-http_access_module --without-http_auth_basic_module --without-http_autoindex_module --without-http_geo_module --without-http_map_module --without-http_split_clients_module --without-http_referer_module --without-http_proxy_module --without-http_fastcgi_module --without-http_uwsgi_module --without-http_scgi_module --without-http_memcached_module --without-http_empty_gif_module --without-http_browser_module --without-http_upstream_ip_hash_module --without-http_upstream_least_conn_module --without-http_upstream_keepalive_module --without-mail_pop3_module --without-mail_imap_module --without-mail_smtp_module
```

Comment: Syntax looks ok. Does your Ngnix build install that module? Nginx -T to check.

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -V`.

Comment: Ahh - thanks, looks like the buildpack I'm using configures nginx without http-access-module - which of course would make this not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comments, it appears that your version of Nginx doesn't include the http-access-module, which implements the deny command.